# Resize table columns evenly

Tags: tables, tabularx, resize

I have the following table which looks like this:

[image]

When the entry "aaaaa...aa" is shorter, it will look like this:

[image]

I want in this case to keep the proportionality between the two columns, but I can not find a solution for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
\textbf{Architecture} & \textbf{Limitations}        \\
                \hline 
\endfirsthead
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  & blah blah baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
            \\  \hline

Header2 &   blah .
            \\ \hline
Header3 &   blah .
            \\ \hline
Header4 &   blah blah .
            \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable. The `table` environment does not accept a width argument, so remove `\{linewidth}` from `\begin{table}`. Also, It don't include a breakable `xltabular` inside of a non-breakable `table`.

Comment: Please also clarify what "keep the proportionality"  means specifically. Do you want both columns to be equally wide regardless of ho long or short their rescpctive contents are? If so, you might want to give `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}` a try. If you're interested in different widths, please specify them.

Comment: By proportionality I mean equal (when the entries in the row are short).  Let's say both columns contain a longer word I want that the first one to grow while the last one is splitted. 

So what I want is that in the second case the size to be equal, but not all the time. In the first case I want column one to resize according to the textwitdh.

Comment: So basically this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1mHa.png

Comment: The main idea is to autosize the columns when column 1 is big, but when there is plenty of space to split them evenly. Not like in the second picture.

Comment: @leandriis yes, like in your picture. But if "aaaa" grows, the second column to be smaller

Comment: Will the text in the first column ever get long enough to need a linebreak there, as well and do you also need the page-breaking ability of `xltabular`? It might also be useful to add this extra information and additional explanations on the size restrictions directly into your question so they don't get lost in the comments.

Comment: Yes, both columns get long. I want that the first one to not have a linebreak while the second one to have one when it's the case. I need xltabular because sometimes the table might be on multiple pages.

Comment: @leandriis can you provide me the solution that you posted in the picture?

Comment: Sure, I can do so, but I manually chose different column types for both tables. For the first one, I used `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}` as in your original question, while I switched to `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}` for the second example.

Comment: You can use a `tabularx` environment (or \ xltabular` if it should break across pages) with  table preamble like `\begin{tabularx}{desired total width}{|>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X|>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X}`. This will make the column widths ratio equal to `3 : 2`.

Comment: For both solutions, if the first column grows then the second one remains the same, and the content will overlap. :( And when the columns are short the table becomes small. I want the same table size either the content is short or not

Comment: Which suggestion does [your recent comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587761/resize-table-columns-evenly?noredirect=1#comment1476698_587761)  refer to? What kind of contents will your table actually contain? I was under the impression stuff like "aaaaa"  was just some random filler. Since this is not a proper word, no hyphenation pattern can be used, resulting in possible overlaps. If you use some real word in your table, this overlap-related issue should not occur any more.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NSMi7wY Here is a more clear picture of what I want